# Rake does not recognize rules with multiple extensions

Tags: rake

I generate PDFs from Markdown files using Rake. If a Markdown file is `filename.md`, I like the PDF to be `filename.md.pdf` not `filename.pdf`, so that autocompletion works the way I like and so that it's clear what the source of the PDF file is.

I have this Rake file, which works fine.

```
MDFILES = FileList["*.md"]
PDFS = MDFILES.ext("pdf")

desc "Build PDFs of all chapters"
task :pdfs => PDFS

# Build PDFs from Markdown source
rule ".pdf" => ".md" do |t|
  sh "pandoc #{t.source} -o #{t.name}"
end
```

If I run `rake pdfs` or `rake filename.pdf` the PDFs are generated as expected, but the PDFs are named `filename.pdf`.

But I want the Rakefile to be this instead:

```
MDFILES = FileList["*.md"]
PDFS = MDFILES.ext("md.pdf")

desc "Build PDFs of all chapters"
task :pdfs => PDFS

# Build PDFs from Markdown source
rule "md.pdf" => ".md" do |t|
  sh "pandoc #{t.source} -o #{t.name}"
end
```

Running `rake pdfs` or `rake filename.md.pdf` returns the error `Don't know how to build task 'filename.md.pdf'`.

How can I produce filenames the way I want?

By the way, this type of rule works fine with Make, to wit:

```
%.md.pdf : %.md
        pandoc $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar problem myself recently when I attempted to specify an extension with multiple dots in a rule. I solved it by using a different rule syntax as described [here.](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/doc/rakefile.rdoc#advanced-rules)

Try something like this for your rule:

```
rule( /\.md\.pdf$/ => [
    proc {|task_name| task_name.sub(/\.md\.pdf$/, '.md') }
]) do |t|
    sh "pandoc #{t.source} -o #{t.name}"
end
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for pointing out that alternative rule syntax. It's certainly more powerful, but a lot uglier than Make's.